# Deleted "broken" certificate in OS X, need help to fix it

Tags: macos, ssl, certificate

I experienced the Mavericks security update that broke one or more trusted root CAs. At the time I couldn't find any info on this, and in my infinite wisdom (and looming deadline) I tried deleting the assumed culprit certificate (VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5), cowboy style - no backup.

Very stupid, but now I hope someone here might know a way to fix this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to download root certificates from here
https://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=roots 
and then import them into your keychain.

Comment: Should have found this when poking around their site earlier, but thanks a lot for the direct link! Looks like my issue is fixed after reinstalling + trusting.